# Jenkins runs maven in a very strange way and fails with android api

Tags: android, maven, jenkins

I need to run simply run `package` goal. Now instead of just running that, I see in the jenkins log something like:

```
$ /usr/java/default//bin/java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-agent-1.4.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.1.1/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.1.1/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.1.1 /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jenkins.war--any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.33.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-interceptor-1.4.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.4.jar 49752
```

and

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HelloAndroid/workspace/pom.xml package
```

and then to fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project ch.usi.inf.sa4.android: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.0:generate-sources failed: Invalid SDK: Platform/API level 19 not available. This command should give you all you need:
[ERROR] /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --obsolete --force
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Whereas just running

```
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.1.1 package
```

manually from the workspace directory succeeds, and yes, there is android 19 API available

Comment: try setting a ANDROID_HOME env variable in jenkins main configuration page (manage Jenkins > configure system > global configuration > global properties), pointing to /opt/android-sdk-linux/

Comment: @guido It's set. As you can see it know that the _android_ executable is in `/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android`